# Add identity numbers to specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data where the combination of programid and rev_id makes primary key. My program Id is redundant for a different reason. So I want to add identity number to rev_id so the primary key rule is not violated.

My current data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Any help?!

Rextester link: https://rextester.com/SJV93546

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number function with partition

```
select
programID,
cast(rev_id as varchar(6)) + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rev_id ORDER BY content ASC) as varchar(2)),
content
 from currentdata
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest expressing this as:

```
select programID,
       (rev_id * 10 + row_number() over (partition by rev_id order by content asc) 
       ) as rev_id,
       content
from currentdata;
```

I see no reason to convert this to a string.